# What is meant by "a linear model applied to the output of the poly() function"?

Tags: data-science-model

Currently, I am studying the third chapter of [*An Introduction to Statistical Learning*](https://www.statlearning.com) with Application in R which discusses linear regression. In **section 3.6.5: Non-linear Transformations of the Predictors** the `poly()` function was used to create a polynomial regression model. After that the writers wrote:

> By default, the poly() function orthogonalizes the predictors: this
> means that the features output by this function are not simply a
> sequence of powers of the argument. However, a linear model applied to
> the output of the poly() function will have the same fitted values as
> a linear model applied to the raw polynomials (although the
> coefficient estimates, standard errors, and p-values will differ). In
> order to obtain the raw polynomials from the poly() function, the
> argument raw = TRUE must be used.

Here I can't understand what the writers meant by " a linear model applied to the output of the poly() function.... ".

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

[Orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) are different to "normal" polynomials. Thus the regression output will be different (coefficients, standard errors etc).

```
library(ISLR)

df = ISLR::Auto

reg1 = lm(mpg~poly(weight,3,raw=F),data=df)
summary(reg1)

reg2 = lm(mpg~poly(weight,3,raw=T),data=df)
summary(reg2)
```

For `reg1` the result is:

```
Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 23.4459     0.2112 111.008  < 2e-16 ***
poly(weight, 3, raw = F)1 -128.4436     4.1817 -30.716  < 2e-16 ***
poly(weight, 3, raw = F)2   23.1589     4.1817   5.538 5.65e-08 ***
poly(weight, 3, raw = F)3    0.2204     4.1817   0.053    0.958
```

For `reg2` the result is:

```
Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                6.170e+01  1.104e+01   5.587 4.36e-08 ***
poly(weight, 3, raw = T)1 -1.793e-02  1.091e-02  -1.643    0.101    
poly(weight, 3, raw = T)2  1.515e-06  3.450e-06   0.439    0.661    
poly(weight, 3, raw = T)3  1.846e-11  3.503e-10   0.053    0.958
```

However, predicted (aka "fitted") values from both models will be same:

```
predict(reg1,newdata=df)[0:3]
       1        2        3 
18.26982 17.07799 18.72854 

predict(reg2,newdata=df)[0:3]
       1        2        3 
18.26982 17.07799 18.72854
```

You also can look the the actual numbers behind the polynomials:

```
poly(df$weight,3,raw=F)[0:3]
[1] 0.03134202 0.04259480 0.02729340

poly(df$weight,3,raw=T)[0:3]
[1] 3504 3693 3436
```

The [`poly`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/poly) function returns "normal" polynomials when `raw=T`. But since these are correlated (and not orthogonal) and since they are simply different numbers (compared to orthogonal polynomials), estimated coefficients etc. in both models above differ.

```
poly(c(1,2,3,4),degree = 2,raw=T)
     1  2
[1,] 1  1
[2,] 2  4
[3,] 3  9
[4,] 4 16
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for your reply. Can you please explain what do you mean by "actual numbers behind polynomial"? Also can you please explain why orthogonal polynomial is better than normal polynomial though they give the same fitted value ( with different coefficient, intercept and p-value)?

Comment: "actual numbers": what you use to train the model ($x$ values), they are different. "Orthogonal" means "not correlated", which can be a desireable property, i.e. in case you are interested in marginal effects from the model since in this case you need to avoid "high correlation" in the $x$ https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64415/71442